# How to make a WCF client ignore the response?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a contract in the same signature as an `Action<T>` delegate:

```
[ServiceContract()]
interface ISomeService
{
    [OperationContract()]
    void DoSomething(object data);
}
```

1. Will the client wait for the server side method execution to finish?
2. If yes, how to prevent this?
3. Should I use async calls to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [one way operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S1).